# Resize layout over time

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, size

I'm trying to resize a layout over time, what I'm stuck on is trying to loop the decrease/increase in size, I've currently got it working to resize on a screen touch.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    // Gets linearlayout
    layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeOne);

    params = layout.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = width - width/2;
    params.width = width - width/2;

    sizeAfter = width;

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    sizeAfter = sizeAfter - 2;
    params.height = sizeAfter;
    params.width = sizeAfter;
return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Currently this works fine, however how would I go about implementing maybe a timer to loop after a set amount of time gradually decreasing the layouts size.

Comment: It may just be easier to use the built-in functionality for layout animations.

Comment: I never even knew that existed, thanks!

Comment: You should try out the API sample demos that you can download through the sdk manager. You should also check out these two showcase open source sample apps. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inappsquared.devappsdirect (Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with either of those projects).